# How to make Windows 10 task bar smaller

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

My task bar is put on the left of screen and it gets full very easily, since my Windows system is 150% enlarged than normal FHD metrics. When full, there will be the second page of the task bar which is very not easy to use. Multiple desktops sort of solve this problem, but it is not as easy as single desktop to use. The option to merge cells is even more not easy to use.

So I want to make the cells just smaller(decreased height, the width can be set freely when the task bar is on the left/right side). I already set it to "small icon", how can I modify the height of cell under small icon setting (e.g. registry)?

Comment: If the Windows default desktop does not suite your needs may be you should think about using an [alternative shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_alternative_shells_for_Windows) instead. The desktop is in the end just an Explorer process launched at start-up. It can be replaced....

Comment: @Robert Open source+Active gives ReactOS...

Answer (score 0):

The smallest task bar is the setting for small icons. Since there are so many (non-Microsoft) icons that have to fit, the small icon setting is as small as you can make it and allow any application icon to fit properly.

Use the setting to "combine like buttons and hide labels" (same taskbar setting screen as the small icons setting).

Consider using smaller screen resolution and fewer active applications to make the icons fit.

Comment: “combine like buttons and hide labels” is this for Windows 10?

Comment: Yes. "Combine buttons.."  is in the taskbar setting screen. (Windows Settings)

Comment: So I was at a meeting this morning. Numerous Word documents open (piled up under Word), Numerous Explorer windows (including DropBox and piled up under Explorer, numerous PDFs open under one Adobe icon, and Excel open. Net result: 4 more icons than normal and only 1/3 of screen width used. Works fine.

Comment: @ John But the question has said combining is not an option. Combination is better for situation like your comment---unbelievable numerous window of few applications. But I generally have <=3 Explorer and Chrome window and I need to switch beween windows for one application easily. If there is a mounse hover---auto show combined list then this may be an option.

Comment: Hovering with mouse shows all the windows so as to select. Works fine.  So also does Alt-Tab